# Transform thumbnail caption with CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I know how to create simple caption and hover captions individually on thumbnail but how to do it together like there is a simple caption on thumbnail and when it get hovered then detail caption is displayed

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="caption">
            <h2>Simple Caption</h2>
            <h3>detail caption</h3>
            <hr>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Shop Now</a></p>
          </div>
          <img src="one.jpg" alt="one">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.caption {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   background:rgba( 235,235,235, 0.91) ;
   color:#5B5E5E !important;
   text-align:center;
   width:350px;
   height:600px;
   padding:150px;
   display:none;
 }
```

**h2** should be visible as a thumbnail caption before hovering.

But when hovered then it should show **h2** along with **h3** and **p**.

Here is the [link](http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/) which shows **NICE LILY**. I want to transform caption like that.

How i can achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a working example in jsfiddle.net

Comment: this is the link http://codepeoples.com/tanimdesign.net/thsop-v-1.3/gray/index5.html in this link you will see thumbnail gallery where it is showing handbags, designers and sale offers. i want effect like handbags, designers and sale offers.

Comment: Why not using the <figcaption> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry didn't see your link... I'll leave my previous answer below in-case someone wants that behavior...[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xp6qjhq/3/)

Instead of display:none on your caption, display none on the items you don't want displayed (h3, p). and then add a hover to the caption and select it's children... You can then add any of the animations you want.

```
.thumbnail { 
    position:relative; 
}

.thumbnail:hover .caption {
    display:block;
}
.caption {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   color:#5B5E5E !important;
   text-align:center;
   width:350px;
   height:600px;
   padding:150px;
   display:block;
}

.caption h3, .caption p {
    display:none;
}

.caption:hover {
    background:rgba( 235,235,235, 0.91) ;
}
.caption:hover h3, .caption:hover p {
    display:block;
}
```

This is what I am assuming you want to happen...

1. User hovers over image and see's simple caption (h2)
2. User then hovers over h2 and shows detail caption (h3)

I have a jsfiddle where you can see the example...[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/1xp6qjhq/1/)

First you need to add a hover to your thumbnail to show the caption. You then need to tell the h3 in caption to hide. You then select the hovered h2 and it's sibling h3 and do a show on it. Note that this wont work on earlier versions of Internet Explorer.  In the end this is what your CSS will look like...

```
.thumbnail { 
    position:relative; 
}

.thumbnail:hover .caption {
    display:block;
}
.caption {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   background:rgba( 235,235,235, 0.91) ;
   color:#5B5E5E !important;
   text-align:center;
   width:350px;
   height:600px;
   padding:150px;
   display:none;
 }

.caption h3 {
    display:none 
}

.caption h2:hover + h3 {
    display:block; 
}
```

Comment: Image should show h2 caption before hovering but when it is hovered then it should show h2 plus h3 and plus p

Comment: But before hovering i also want to hide the hr too. hr should show only when it is hovered

Comment: I've already provided the basic structure for you, just look at the css and replicate the selectors for the hr that I have for h3 and P tags.